# Short exact sequence of abelian groups implies long exact sequnce of cohomologies

Tags: group-theory, homological-algebra

I am trying to compute cohomologies $H^i(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z})$. Actually it is not a big deal, because I have already computed $H^i(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z})$ and now I can use Künneth theorem. However, I can use instead the following fact, which seems to be valid:

Suppose we have an exact sequence of abelian groups
$$0\to N\to G\to T\to0.$$
Then we have an exact sequence of cohomologies
$$...\to H^{i-1}(G,\mathbb{Z})\to H^i(T,\mathbb{Z})\to H^i(G, \mathbb{Z})\to H^i(N,\mathbb{Z})\to H^{i+1}(T,\mathbb{Z})\to...$$

The question is, is this fact true or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so. We could for example take $N=G={\mathbb Z}$ and $T={\mathbb Z}/n{\mathbb Z}$ for some $n>1$. Then $H^{2k}(T,{\mathbb Z}) ={\mathbb Z}/n{\mathbb Z}$, but all other terms in the sequence are $0$.

Comment: You are right. Thank you.